# XML does not render after making an ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, laravel-blade

I am trying to make an ajax call and on the server accessing a field from the table I have the following:

```
<PushProperty><Status ID = "1"> Success </Status><ResponseID> b3633c9eeb13498f </ResponseID><ID> 9098 </ID></PushProperty>
```

I want this result to be displayed with its respective format and labels and I cannot get it.

In the controller I have the following:

```
class RequestResponseController extends Controller
{
    public function show_data(Request $request){

        $rr = RequestResponse::find( $request->id);

        $text = $rr->response;

        return $text;

    }
}
```

And from view I call it with ajax:

```
function show_request_response (id, type) {

    $.ajax ({
        url: "/request_responses/show_data",
        data: {
            "_token": "{{csrf_token ()}}",
             "id" : id,
            "type": type,
        },
        method: "POST",
        async: false,
        success: function (xmlResponse) {

            $ ('# exampleModal'). modal ('show');
            $ ('# exampleModal .modal-title'). html ("Response XML");
            $ ('# exampleModal .modal-body'). html (xmlResponse);

        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

But in the modal it shows me only text without xml tags, that is:

Successb3633c9eeb13498f9098

But I need to get:

```
<PushProperty>
     <Status ID="1">Success</Status> 
     <ResponseID>b3633c9eeb13498f</ResponseID> 
     <ID>9098</ID>
</PushProperty>
```

I hope it helps me thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using jQuery's `html()` method which tells it to parse the input as HTML.

In HTML `<this>` is a tag and isn't rendered as plain text.

Use the `text()` method if you want to tell jQuery to render the input as text instead of HTML source code.